# Have npm create the bin/*.cmd files when installing from Linux?

Tags: node.js, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When using node.js in the [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq), it's inconvenient that running `npm install` from within the WSL does not create the `node_modules/bin/*.cmd` files that some Windows-based tools look for.

Is it possible to have these created when I install any package?

Or should I look for a solution that creates them, outside of the `npm` command?

Comment: I dont understand the question, Are you looking for a solution for create `node_modules/bin/*.cmd` (or else do something pragmatically) after a npm module (module that you published)  installed.

Comment: @JanithKasun this is as a package user, not as a package author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `node_modules/bin/*.cmd` to be created, you'll need to install the Windows version of node. Remember that WSL looks and feels like Linux. The node modules you want created don't exist on Linux, so WSL won't create this either. It is common enough for node to be installed on both Windows and WSL. Just be sure to make your WSL node path appear before your Windows node path. It is generally good practice for all your Windows paths to append at the end of your PATH to allow WSL to try and perform an action using the Linux tools you install first before attempting to use the Windows binary.

Comment: @robertkbell, if you found my answer helpful, please accept it by placing a checkmark by it.

Comment: Having node/npm installed on both Windows & WSL is fine, but it goes off the rails when interacting with the local `node_modules` folder with a mix of Win & WSL.

Comment: Yeah you need to be careful but it's manageable. Thanks for upvoting.